# Lexicographic rank of permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Let $\mathrm{rank _ L}$ be the rank relative to the lexicographic order for $\sigma$ $\in$  $\mathrm{S_9}$. If $\mathrm{rank _ L(\sigma)}$ = 49280, which value will assume $\sigma(9)$?

To answer this question, I'm applying integer division of $\mathrm{49280}$ by $\mathrm{8!}$, then applying integer division of $\mathrm{8960}$ by 7! and so on. Keeping track of the quotient at each step, I'd reconstruct the permutation $\sigma$, arriving at $\mathrm{[2,3,8,5,7,4,9]}$ but maybe this is an inefficient way to do it... Any suggestions?

Comment: Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system